# Maui Windows Applications have a disturbing gray line at the top of every window

Tags: .net, maui, .net-maui

I have written some test projects with Maui Preview 10 an 11.

In both Versions there is a 2 pixel height gray line on top of the window that isn't defined in my Application.

It occures on Windows, but not on Android.

Does anyone else the same problem? Does anyone have an idea where it come from?

The Screenshot is from the default Maui Template App, only Changed the background color.

I also tried to set all padding and margins to 0.

Any ideas?

Thanks CeeJay

[Screenshot with gray line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4izKR.png)

Comment: I try to create a new maui project, try to modify the background color, and your situation does not appear, the modified background color is filled.

Comment: Strange, i will try to test on different computers und resolutions

Comment: Yes is see what you mean , if you zoom in there is a small Greyline . Think it is the border of the top bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small Update here,

Problem is gone in Maui Preview 12

[image: Maui Preview 12]